# mysql concatenate data only if field already has value

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to update a mysql table in my php application.  This is what I'm trying to figure out:

If "my-field" does not contain any data I want to update that field with a particular data string.

If "my-field" already contains data I would like to concatenate more data to it separated by a comma.

"my-field" is set up as "NOT NULL"

Below is the code I'm using, which I feel is close to what I need but it does not work.

```
UPDATE my-table SET 
my-field = 
  IF( 
    LENGTH('my-field'), 
    CONCAT_WS(
      CHAR(44 USING UTF8), 
     'my-field', 
     'if-my-field-has-length-data'
    ), 
 'if-my-field-has-NO-length-data');
```

I've tried the code below as well.  It actually works.  However, it always ends up adding a comma to the beginning like such:

`note the comma here =>            ,data-set-1,data-set-2`

I'm looking for a result like this:

`note no comma on first data set => data-set-1,data-set-2`

```
UPDATE my-table SET 
my-field = 
  CONCAT_WS(
    CHAR(44 USING UTF8), 
    'my-field', 
    'general-data'
  )
```

Does anyone know how to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from 'my-field':

```
UPDATE my-table SET 
my-field = 
  IF( 
LENGTH(my-field), 
CONCAT_WS(
  CHAR(44 USING UTF8), 
 my-field, 
 'if-my-field-has-length-data'
), 
 'if-my-field-has-NO-length-data');
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't suggest storing values in comma-delimited strings.  Let me assume that you have to, for some reason:

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET myfield = CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(myfield, ','), ''), @newvalue)
    WHERE . . .;
```

Really, though, you should be using a junction table, with one row per field value and per id in your table.

Comment: There are many valid reasons why one would store comma-delimited strings. It could be that there is no need to query based on data in the field and any parsing of the data would occur in a completely separate layer of the application.

Comment: Correct, I will not need to query the data.  Just looking for a clean way to store an ongoing list that I can easily parse with PHP at a later date.  Plus your code still places a comma in the beginning when myfield is empty

Comment: @Austin . . . This does not add a comma when `myfield` is initially `NULL`.

Comment: my table uses NOT NULL